# Moment time zone format giving invalid date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following time and date in this formate

```
Mon Aug 22 23:32:59 +0000 2016
```

and I want to convert it to  los angeles time, however A) it gives out invalid date. and B) if i remove the last parameter "UTC" it gives out the right time but wrong minutes.

I am passing it to moment time zone as follows

```
 var a = moment.tz("Mon Aug 22 23:32:59 +0000 2016", "ddd MMM DD HH:MM:SS ZZ YYYY", "UTC");
        var b = a.tz("America/Los_Angeles");
        console.log(b.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM A"));
```

But its giving me `Invalid date` and I am unable to figure out the issue.
any clarification would be helpful

**UPDATE**
fixed the issue of invalid date

```
var a = moment("Mon Aug 22 23:32:59 +0000 2016","ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss ZZ YYYY");
```

Also fixed the moments issue, which was due to the fact that i was using capital HH and MM rather than hh:mm which i should've been using.

Comment: In C, the days would be 'dd' and months 'mm', while minutes would be 'MM' and seconds 'SS'.  I note that August is month 8.  Double check the case of the letters in your mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), your format string is wrong.

```
console.log(b.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A"));
```

It shows `08` for minutes, as `MM` (uppercase M) is the token for Months (August = 08), while `mm` is the token for minutes. This is also the reason with the `Invalid date`, it tried to parse the minutes as months, but couldn't. In the Update your capitalization is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This works in my terminal:

```
var a = moment.tz("Mon Aug 22 23:32:59 +0000 2016", "ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss Z YYYY", "UTC");
var b = a.tz("America/Los_Angeles");
console.log(b.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A"));
```

What's wrong in your code is the minute, second and offset part. Check te document here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/